# CI ERROR :Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

i'm trying to insert multiple array to mysql, but getting error like this

> Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array
>
> Filename: operator_pt/Wsmahasiswa.php
>
> Line Number: 357

here my code from controller

```
$database1 = $username1.'_'.$token.'_'.$temphmspt;
        $table1 = 'mahasiswa';
        $data1 = $this->db->query("select nm_pd from $database1");
        foreach($data1->result() as $key1){
        $filter1 = "nm_pd like '$key1->nm_pd'";
        $order1 = "nm_pd asc";
        $limit1 = 10;
        $offset1 = 0;
        $tampan1 = $proxy->GetRecordset($token, $table1, $filter1, $order1, $limit1, $offset1);
        $tampan1=$data1;
        $insert = $this->db->replace($database, $data1["result"]); //line 357

    }
```

here arrays example

```
Array
(
    [error_code] => 0
    [error_desc] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_pd] => cb5ab906-a9b5-49f2-95e9-0d30ce005bd9
                    [nm_pd] => BABABA

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_pd] => f29128c2-27a0-4300-a4f5-842573e9e804
                    [nm_pd] => BIBIBI

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [error_code] => 0
    [error_desc] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_pd] => 70500b08-a285-4e97-af0c-e8e43d2e5be6
                    [nm_pd] => BUBUBU

                )
```

Comment: You did not use `result()` like this `$data1["result"]`

Comment: do you mean like this ? $insert = $this->db->replace($database, $data1->result());

Comment: What you want to do using `$data1["result"]`?

Answer (score 1):

use `$data1->result_array()` instead of `$data1->result()` it will give you result in array